# Reading jquery from it's site in https

Tags: jquery, web, https

I was using jquery directly from their site, using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />');
```

and same as for UI javascript.

I have moved the domain to https, in IE and chrome the files are not loaded.
in chrome it shows

```
[blocked] The page at https://compute.amazonaws.com:8443/my-web/application ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js.
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot by default load **NON** ssl URLs from within an SSL page. This is a security restriction that should NEVER be disabled. e.g. you must use an `https://` url to load jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If a page is loaded over HTTPS then every resource it uses should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Otherwise a man-in-the-middle could replace images with misleading ones (or ones that exploit buffer overflow issues in browsers to execute code) and scripts with ones that do different things (such as leak data to the third party).

And In your case just host your jquery and ui library on the same https server, and access them through it.

Comment: Ok that i will do to bundle it in same server.
but isn't it a overhead to get the js and css files though https? is there any way i can get it via http?